# Get body from POST in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am very new to Flask and have the following Flask code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/test/<email>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'], strict_slashes=False)
def test(email):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("USERS_EMAIL: ", email)
        return 'GET REQUEST', 202

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("USERS_EMAIL: ", email)
        body = request.json['email_subject']
        print("BODY: ", body)
        return '', 201
    return 'ERROR', 400
```

I need to send a JSON object from my react frontend end retrieve it in Flask. I am sending the following body in POSTMAN but I get this error every time (at the bottom of the post):

**BODY:**

```json
{
  "email_subject": "Postman test",
  "title": "Lysenko Ilya Igorevich"
}
```

**Things I have tried:**

I found these two links ([link1](https://dev.to/dev_elie/sending-data-from-react-to-flask-apm), [link2](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/sending-a-post-to-your-flask-api-from-a-react-js-app-6496692514e)) which seemed to be saying two different things, so first I tried both of these options:

```py
body = request.json['body']
```

```py
body = request.get_json()
```

neither which worked. I was then wondering whether the name in the square brackets refers not to the body but to the key in the body, so I then tried the following:

```py
body = request.json['email_subject']
```

which did not work either. Any suggestions?

*(screenshot of my postman error)*

[image]

Comment: I suspect the problem is how you're sending the request in Postman.  Click the "Text" pulldown menu and select JSON.

Comment: so `request.json['email_subject']` gets a the value of that key from the object? is there a way to get the whole object?

Comment: I assume `request.json` is the whole object.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue! I can't accept a comment as an answer though...